# Google Sheets IF Conditioning

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use conditional formatting based on another file's cell, however the colours never seem to change.

I have 1 Google Sheet that I use to organise the people's names.

Then I have another sheet that is cleaner on which I am using `IMPORTRANGE`. On this sheet I want to apply conditional formatting based on a `TRUE` x `FALSE` value "Checkbox" from sheet number 1.

On the conditional formatting I placed this value:

```
=IF("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iyvn8ErdmXttX6zAZ4ZzcplzNuYaszTwSngcaV7zZxE", "EveningRounds!E9=TRUE")
```

But nothing seems to happen to it when the cell has `TRUE` on it.

Where could I have gone wrong?

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Welcome. You are jumping right into the other spreadsheet without opening it. Have you tried opening that spreadsheet first; setting the value in 'EveningRounds!E9' to a variable, and THEN use the variable in the If statement. You need to research `openById` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) and/or `openByUrl` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)